# Inheritance and Extension in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been playing with ruby and have a bit in  my understanding of inheritance and mixins.
Consider the following code:

```
module Base
  class Parent
    def foo
      "hello parent"
    end
  end

  module Extension
    module Extender
      def bar
        "hello extended"
      end
    end
  end
  module Tasks
    class Child < Base::Parent
      extend Base::Extension::Extender
      def blah
        puts "blah"
        puts foo
        puts self.bar
      end
    end
  end
end

Base::Tasks::Child.new().blah
```

blah fails at 'bar', claiming it's undefined.
The context for this is that I want to use methods from Parent, but pull in some options and/or configuration from Extender that may be used in Parent as well. With this setup, I'd expect bar to be pulled into Child as a class variable, but clearly, it isn't.

Is there a better way to organize this, or am I misunderstanding how extend works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `include` to make `bar` an instance method, not `extend`. With `extend`, you've made `bar` a class-level method; you'd have to access it via `Child.bar`.

So either of these:

```
class Child < Base::Parent
  extend Base::Extension::Extender
  def blah
    puts Child.bar
```

or

```
class Child < Base::Parent
  include Base::Extension::Extender
  def blah
    puts self.bar
```